# /icons, /images, /avatars do not work with Vaadin @Endpoint annotation

Tags: push-notification, vaadin, endpoint, vaadin-spring-boot

I have vaadin spring-boot project with vaadin 21, java 16, spring-boot 2.5.4.
I added push notifications mixed from this [**guide**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5sbGvW3S4I&t=1s) and this [**guide**](https://vaadin.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-sending-web-push-notifications-from-vaadin-flow)
Since i added MessageEndPoint with Vaadin @Endpoint annotation, i have this mistake

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

with 405 mistake in browser console and my icons and images from /resourses folder do not load

MessageEndpoint class code:

```
@Endpoint
@AnonymousAllowed
@RestController
@RequestMapping("connect/MessageEndpoint")
public class MessageEndpoint {

    @PostMapping(value = "/getPublicKey")
    public @Nonnull String getPublicKey() {
        return PushNotificationService.INSTANCE.getPublicKey();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/subscribe", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void subscribe( @RequestBody Object subscription, String userGuid) {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String value = om.writeValueAsString(((LinkedHashMap) subscription).get("subscription"));
            String guid = om.writeValueAsString(((LinkedHashMap) subscription).get("userGuid"));
            MSubscription subscription1 = om.readValue(value, MSubscription.class);
            PushNotificationService.INSTANCE.subscribe(subscription1, guid.substring(1, guid.length() - 1));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/unsubscribe", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void unsubscribe( @RequestBody Object subscription, String userGuid) {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String value = om.writeValueAsString(((LinkedHashMap) subscription).get("subscription"));
            String guid = om.writeValueAsString(((LinkedHashMap) subscription).get("userGuid"));
            MSubscription subscription1 = om.readValue(value, MSubscription.class);
            PushNotificationService.INSTANCE.unsubscribe(subscription1, guid.substring(1, guid.length() - 1));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1. I tried to remove @Endpoint annotation but without it push notifications do not work
2. I tried to do some magic with spring security config. I thought it could help fix 405 mistake

Comment: The error states, that GET is not supported - and your controller only has POST-methods

Comment: Note: Vaadin 21, Java 16 and Spring Boot 2.5 are EoL.